# Can someone explain what this log_normal_pdf term means for the tensorflow VAE demo code?

Tags: python, tensorflow

It doesnt appear to be a regular log norm pdf as seen in https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Log-normal_distribution

https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/generative/cvae

```
def log_normal_pdf(sample, mean, logvar, raxis=1):
  log2pi = tf.math.log(2. * np.pi)
  return tf.reduce_sum(
      -.5 * ((sample - mean) ** 2. * tf.exp(-logvar) + logvar + log2pi),
      axis=raxis)
```

Answer (score 3):

This is the logarithm of the probability according to a normal distribution. I.e. `log(p(x))` where `p` is a normal/Gaussian distribution. The naming *is* a little confusing though.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, Could I clarify though. for the Log(P(x)) shouldn't I expect to see a different form. Particularly with the exponential term gone? Do you know where I can find a reference?

Comment: The exponential term is gone. The `tf.exp` you see in the code is because the function takes the _log_ variance, and `exp` turns it into the actual variance.

Answer (score 2):

In case anyone else wanders down this rabbit hole, the previous answer checks out: "the logarithm of the pdf according to a normal distribution". Here's a simple check that you can run based on the [gaussian function definition from wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gaussian_function):

```
import numpy as np

def log_normal_pdf(sample, mean, std):
    """Function from tensorflow VAE example"""
    logvar = np.log(std**2)
    log2pi = np.log(2*np.pi)
    return -.5 * ((sample - mean) ** 2. * np.exp(-logvar) + logvar + log2pi)

def test(sample, mean, std):
    """Alternate calc taking the log of the wiki gaussian function"""
    out = (1 / (std * np.sqrt(2*np.pi))) * np.exp(-0.5 * (sample-mean)**2 / std**2)
    return np.log(out)

print(log_normal_pdf(9, 10, 1))
print(test(9, 10, 1))
```